# how do i get data from init.js in messageVIew?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I have to get users_url in messageView. Can you help me?

init.js

```
(function(global) {
    "use strict;"

    // Class ------------------------------------------------
    function Config() {

        var users_url = "some_url";

    };

    Config.defaultContainer = "body";

    // Exports ----------------------------------------------
    module["exports"] = Config;

})((this || 0).self || global);
```

and this is my messageView.js where I want to get users_url from init.js.

```
var init = require('../../../init.js');

var MessagingView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el : null,

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.el = options.el;
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(template());
        this.onLoad();  
        return this;

    },
    onLoad: function(){         
        consle.log("Here i want my users_url");
        });
    } 
});

module.exports = MessagingView;
```

I've tried everything and i can get it.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error message? Could you create an example on https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: there is no error message. i just want to fetch users_url from init.js into messageView.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Where is the code which supposed to fetch `users_url`?

Comment: init.users_url , init.get(users_url) .. nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, `users_url` is a variable inside the `Config` (or, `init`) function. Since JavaScript has function scope, a variable created inside a function can't be reached from outside that function.

You could make `users_url` a property of the `Config` function, like you've done with `defaultContainer`. Then in `messageView.js`, you would do `init.users_url`.

You could make the `Config` function return `users_url`, or an object with that as a property:

```
function Config () {
    // ...
    return {
        users_url: users_user
    };
}
```

Then, in `messageView.js`, you would do something like:

```
init().users_url
// or
var obj = init();
obj.users_url
```

Comment: You sir deserve a beer! Thank you very much!